# Streaming Live Audio Through the Browser (HTML5??)

Tags: html, audio-streaming, html5-audio, shoutcast, icecast

I've looked round for a few days now and can't seem to find anything.

What I'm looking to do is to take an audio source, from a single single microphone - ideally this will be done in the browser, I want to reduce the need for any plugins and limit the use of flash if at all possible. I would then look at broadcasting this audio stream to multiple clients (much like internet radio I guess), again all done in the browser. I've looked at things like icecast and shoutcast and they seem to to do what I need for this end.

What I need to know is if it is possible to capture an audio stream completely through a browser?

(Note: This will be sitting in a ASP.Net application)

Comment: Hi Daniel, I see that WebRTC api is an accepted option. Can you guide me if you were able to achieve results with this solution, I would really appreciate if you can share with me sources that helped you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try the WebRTC api that is on progress. The Api does just like what you're doing.

Answer (score 0):

for HTML5 you can simply use the  tag, however, as of today, firefox will not support MP3 broadcasting with that, why? because of some copyright stuff, however they are working on it and i heard a couple of days that it will be available natively for firefox.

check this stream, it uses  tag, run it on iexplorer or chrome, even safari will work

geekius.net/radio